# Software Center "Reinstall Previous Purchases" and "Sync Between Computers" not working

Tags: software-center

It's been a while now (almost a year?) but even after upgrading to 15.10 GNOME, I still  cannot reinstall previous purchases or sync software packages across computers any more like it used to be.

Choosing either of the two options in Software Center menu File, results in these messages in Syslog:

```
Nov  7 23:38:05 Aspire-V5 /usr/lib/gdm/gdm-x-session[6011]: Activating service name='com.ubuntu.sso'
Nov  7 23:38:05 Aspire-V5 /usr/lib/gdm/gdm-x-session[6011]: Successfully activated service 'com.ubuntu.sso'
Nov  7 23:38:05 Aspire-V5 ubuntu-software-center.desktop[3244]: 2015-11-07 23:38:05,534 - softwarecenter.backend.login_impl.login_sso - ERROR - _on_credentials_error for Ubuntu One: dbus.Dictionary({dbus.String(u'errtype'): dbus.String(u'GUINotAvailableError'), dbus.String(u'message'): dbus.String(u'Can not find a GUI to present to the user (tried with "(\'ubuntu-sso-login-qt\', \'ubuntu-sso-login-qt\')"). Aborting.')}, signature=dbus.Signature('ss')) ()
Nov  7 23:38:05 Aspire-V5 ubuntu-software-center.desktop[3244]: 2015-11-07 23:38:05,535 - softwarecenter.backend.login_impl.login_sso - ERROR - _on_credentials_error for Ubuntu One: dbus.Dictionary({dbus.String(u'errtype'): dbus.String(u'GUINotAvailableError'), dbus.String(u'message'): dbus.String(u'Can not find a GUI to present to the user (tried with "(\'ubuntu-sso-login-qt\', \'ubuntu-sso-login-qt\')"). Aborting.')}, signature=dbus.Signature('ss')) ()
```

I checked and ubuntu-sso-client is installed...

EDIT: this question is NOT about the discontinued Ubuntu One or similar/alternative sync services! It's about Software Center's Sync feature that allows a sync of installed software packages.

Comment: This is a duplicate of several other questions on the site.  According to those questions, when Ubuntu One shut down their servers, it killed the sync functionality.  I can only guess why the command wasn't removed from the software center.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With Ubuntu One shut down, is there a way to sync applications between computers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/456192/with-ubuntu-one-shut-down-is-there-a-way-to-sync-applications-between-computers)

Comment: Hi Organic, thanks for the input. I'm not talking about syncing a folder or even a user across computers. The sync function in Software Center synced installed packages. That's something different from UbuntuOne or any of the alternatives suggested in the thread you suggest there as possible duplicate. That said, it does look like Ubuntu SSO and UbuntuOne are closely related so you may still be right about the fact that shutting down UbuntuOne killed Ubuntu SSO. Can anybody confirm this?

Comment: @user17254 Ubuntu SSO is just an openID provider. Entirely separate from the Ubuntu One file service. You still use it to log into Launchpad and other Ubuntu related services (you can use it to log into this site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that none of the options are working for, like myself, you can just delete software center using sudo apt-get purge software-center and then sudo apt-get remove software-center and then reinstall using sudo apt-get install software-center. Once you reinstall it, open it and go into file->reinstall previous purchases and make sure that they are asking you to sign into an account to view that. Do not sign into your old account, but rather go to All Software and search steam again. Click Buy and then make a new Ubuntu One account with a new email, verify it, and then the installation process should complete unhindered!

Comment: Hi Philip, even though my question was not about Steam ;) I'm going to mark this as answered because indeed purging (and deleting ~/.config/software-center just to be sure) and reinstalling allowed me to connect with my existing launchpad account. Thanks !